# First Element of array not empty, pointer dereference

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, microcontroller

i am writing code for a microcontroller.

I have the following example so far:

```
// weekly table[timeslot][day]
const int _rows = 7;
const int _cols = 12;
const int _num_weekly_table = _rows * _cols;
uint32_t weekly_table[_rows][_cols];

// pointer pointing start of array weekly array
uint32_t *ptr_weekly_table = &weekly_table[0][0];

int progress_weekly_table = 0;
bool weekly_table_full = false;

/*
 * according to progress_weekly_table save a value in the weekly_table
 */
void append_weekly_table( uint32_t value)
{
    //insert element
    printf(*ptr_weekly_table);
    *(ptr_weekly_table + progress_weekly_table) = value;
    //increase progress
    progress_weekly_table++;
    //if the table is full set flag
    if (progress_weekly_table > _num_weekly_table) {
        weekly_table_full = true;
    }
}
```

During the main loop I run this line:

```
            append_weekly_table(1);
```

But the resulting array does not have a 1 as the first element, instead a 3200171746 (reproducable).All other elements in the array are 1 if i continue to run append_weekly_array.

What is my error here? Quite new to pointers so I don't know if this is the issue.

Comment: This call printf(*ptr_weekly_table); has undefined behavior.

Comment: The code shall not compile because you may not use such declaraions like this const int _num_weekly_table = _rows * _cols; in the global scope.

Comment: And the condition in the if statement     if (progress_weekly_table > _num_weekly_table) {
        weekly_table_full = true; is also wrong. There should be     if (progress_weekly_table == _num_weekly_table) {
        weekly_table_full = true;

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The code compiles with the const declarations in CCS, altough with warnings. The behaviour is the same if I call the array directly with [7][12]. 

Regarding an example: what is the best way to find test if the code I post is reproducable and complete? I tried copy pasting and then deleting all uneccessay lines on something like www.onlinegdb.com but It didnt work because uint_32t is undefined.

Comment: @uuser9630998 You nshould not rely on compiler language extensions.

Comment: Names starting with underscore at file-scope are reserved for the implementation. IOW: You must not use them in the application code. Re the array lengths being variables: do you **really** complie as C code? It's not valid and causes trouble at best. Used macros instead of the variables. It would be valid in C++, though. It's a different language. I don't support eh general statement "don't use compiler extensions", but if there is a straight-forward, and cannonical standard way, use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters these declarations

```
const int _num_weekly_table = _rows * _cols;
uint32_t weekly_table[_rows][_cols];
```

are invalid if they are declarations in the global namespace because 1) you may not initialize a variable with the static storage duration with a non-constant expression and 2) you may not declare Variable Length Arrays with the static storage duration.

It seems you are compiling your program as a C++ program instead of as a C program.

In any case the function `append_weekly_table` is invalid.
For example this statement

```
printf(*ptr_weekly_table);
```

does not make sense because the first parameter of the function has type `const char *`.

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And initially the object `*ptr_weekly_table` has inderterminate value (if the program is a C program and the array does not have the static storage duration; otherwise the object is zero initialized).

Also this condition

```
if (progress_weekly_table > _num_weekly_table) {
    weekly_table_full = true;
}
```

also is wrong. It should be written like

```
if (progress_weekly_table == _num_weekly_table) {
    weekly_table_full = true;
}
```

If you want to compile your program as a C program then the variables _rows and _cols must be declared at least like

```
enum {  _rows = 7,  _cols = 12 };
```

Also it is a bad idea to use leading underscores in variable names because such names are reserved by the system.

Here is a demonstrative C program that can compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

enum {  _rows = 7,  _cols = 12 };
const int _num_weekly_table = _rows * _cols;
uint32_t weekly_table[_rows][_cols];

// pointer pointing start of array weekly array
uint32_t *ptr_weekly_table = &weekly_table[0][0];

int progress_weekly_table = 0;
bool weekly_table_full = false;

void append_weekly_table( uint32_t value)
{
    *(ptr_weekly_table + progress_weekly_table) = value;
    //increase progress
    progress_weekly_table++;
    //if the table is full set flag
    if (progress_weekly_table == _num_weekly_table) {
        weekly_table_full = true;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    append_weekly_table( 1 );

    printf( "ptr_weekly_table[0] = %d\n", *ptr_weekly_table );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
ptr_weekly_table[0] = 1
```

You could substitute these two statements

```
*(ptr_weekly_table + progress_weekly_table) = value;
//increase progress
progress_weekly_table++;
//if the table is full set
```

with one statement

```
ptr_weekly_table[progress_weekly_table++] = value;
```

Comment: thank you for the comments, will try to improve my code with these hints. 

I figured out my problem, it was unrealted to pinters. The value i passed to append_weekly was not initialized proberly and therefore was not 0;

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is most likely this this:

```
printf(*ptr_weekly_table);
```

The expression `*ptr_weekly_table` an `uint32_t` value. Not a string (`char *`) which [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) expects. Because you in effect pass a null pointer (since `ptr_weekly_table[0]` is supposedly zero) then you will ask `printf` to print whatever "string" is at location zero, and that will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To print the correct value use something like

```
printf("%"PRIu32"\n", ptr_weekly_table[0]);
```

See e.g. [this format specifier macro reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer#Format_macro_constants) for information about `PRIu32`.

---

And as you can see I used `ptr_weekly_table[0]` to get the first value of the array. The expressions `ptr_weekly_table[0]` and `*ptr_weekly_table` are equal.

In fact, for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is exactly equal to `*(p + i)`. Which means `*(ptr_weekly_table + progress_weekly_table)` could be written `ptr_weekly_table[progress_weekly_table]` (which is a couple of characters less to write, as well as often more readable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I put the printf there to get some debug output on the console. Even with it not there the first value is not 0. 

The tip regading ptr_weekly_table[progress_weekly_table] is really useful regarding readability, thank you I will use it from now on.

Comment: @user9630998 Then you need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.